# adding to an existing antlr tree

Tags: parsing, tree, antlr, antlr4

I have generated a parse tree like so:

```
afs = new AntlrFileStream(fn);
lexer = new Verilog2001Lexer(afs);
cts = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
parser = new Verilog2001Parser(cts);
tree = parser.source_text();
```

I would like to create new nodes from tokens in the HIDDEN channel and add them to the parse tree.  So I would to ask how you can create new nodes from tokens?  Then how would I add them to a desired location in the parse tree?  I have been looking at the IParseTree interface and Context objects and I have not been able to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 2):

As of ANTLR 4.1, there is no direct support for this in the runtime. In addition, the parse tree is intended to always be valid in the context of a particular grammar; if you add nodes to it from tokens originally on the `HIDDEN` channel, you will break this invariant.

Instead of modifying the parse tree itself, you should attach the additional information to the parse tree nodes by defining a [`ParseTreeProperty<T>`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeProperty.html) instance for each property you are working with, and assign property values for particular `ParseTree` instances.

Comment: Show would the following approximate your idea:

ParseTreeProperty<String> WS = new ParseTreeProperty<String>();
WS.put(node, <Whitespace or comment text>);